# Heroku - Update db column each 1st of the month

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

In my app I have a `Budget` model with `daily_avg` column.
Also there are `BudgetIncome` and `BudgetSpending` models.

```
daily_avg = (BudgetIncome.sum(:debit) - BudgetSpending.sum(:credit))/Time.days_in_month(current_month)
```

I need to update this column every 1st day of month, cause in every month there're different quantity of days.

So, I'll write the script, but I don't know:

1. Where to put this script?
2. How to start it every 1st day of month?

I'm using PostgreSQL and deploying my app on Heroku.

Thanks for any help.

It's the first time I'm working with scripts for DB, so I don't know what information I need to provide you to help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku has a scheduler you can use:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

"Scheduler is an add-on for running jobs on your app at scheduled time intervals, much like cron in a traditional server environment."

Install with: `$ heroku addons:add scheduler:standard`